# builder.addCase does not change the state & does not console log

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Hello i have a very strange problem.
I fetch data with the CreateAsyncThunk and receive them well but the state is not changing

```
const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  status: "idle", //idle | loading | success | failed
  error: null,
};

export const fetchPosts = createAsyncThunk("posts/fetchPosts", async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(POSTS_URL);
  return response.data;
});
```

Here is my addCase :

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
  builder.addCase(fetchPosts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    state.status = "success";
    console.log("test")
    state.posts = action.payload;
  });
},
```

[Here is my Redux devtools action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWOeD.png)
[Here is my Redux devtools state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn8GQ.png)

Even the console logs inside my addCase are not showing

It looks like it dont go inside any addCase

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your response @vladimir but i just found what was my error....

I simply had the extraReducers INSIDE the reducers block.

[And it was fixed simply by moving the extraReducers OUTSIDE the reducers block.... Newbie problem :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26wZ5.png)